# Spring Boot executable jar size 195MB has 25 seconds overhead if liquibase is on classpath

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

My spring boot 1.5.8 JAR-packed application size=195MB, with empty configuration (no any bean)

started with `java -jar` has startup time:

> (main) Started DemoApplication2 in 25.694 seconds (JVM running for 28.267)

However, when I start application with `mvn spring-boot:run` it is much faster

> (restartedMain) Started DemoApplication2 in 2.138 seconds (JVM running for 3.611)

Reason is liqubase classpath scanning. Although I have no Spring configuration for liquibase, Spring Boot class `LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener` automatically initiates costly classpath scanning

I find a workaround: If I start application with

```
-Dliquibase.scan.packages=liquibase.change,liquibase.changelog,liquibase.database,liquibase.parser,liquibase.precondition,liquibase.datatype,liquibase.serializer,liquibase.sqlgenerator,liquibase.executor,liquibase.snapshot,liquibase.logging,liquibase.diff,liquibase.structure,liquibase.structurecompare,liquibase.lockservice,liquibase.sdk.database,liquibase.ext
```

I can skip initial classpath scanning

Sample project: https://github.com/michaldo/slow-by-liquibase

Comment: whats the java version your maven uses and whats the java version you use to execute it? I don't know of a difference, but maybe this could cause this behavior?

Comment: Could you show us your pom.xml, or provide a sample project on github?

Comment: @ÁkosRatku, good point. I made sample application with similar size and it starts very fast. I will continue investigation